# Convert WMA and AAC to MP3 in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I'm looking for an Java API able to convert various audio formats, especially WMA and AAC, to MP3. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you will find native code for that, but you can take a look at one of the Java wrappers from ffmpeg like [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/) or [Jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/).